# Using flutter Webview app, appears black screen at ios

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import FirebaseMessaging
import FirebaseCore
import Firebase
import flutter_local_notifications

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
      FirebaseApp.configure();

      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback {(registry) in
          //GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: registry)
      }

      if #available(iOS 13.0, *){
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
      }

      let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
          options: authOptions,
          completionHandler: { _, _ in }
      )

      application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
      Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
      GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
      //return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
      return true
  }
    func application(application: UIApplication,
                     didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
      Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    }

   override func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
       return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
   }

   override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
   }


}

extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate{
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?){
        let token = String(describing: fcmToken)
        print("Firebase registration token: \(token)")

        let dataDict: [String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(
            name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"),
            object: nil,
            userInfo: dataDict
        )
    }
}
```

I made a android app with flutter webview.
In android device, it works successfully, but in ios environment it just shows me black screen.
Are there some wrong lines?

I expect app to show me normal screen...
This is first time making app, so I don't have enough experience..